# custom environment variable for freedesktop application

Tags: gnome, kde, freedesktop

Do Freedesktop-conforming desktop environments (e.g. KDE, GNOME, and GNOME 2 derivatives) support a method for running all instances of some particular application, whether invoked as a default application for a particular file type or from the application menu, with some particular environment-variable setting, without any increment to the total count of entries in the application menu visible to the user?

Use of custom `.desktop` files in a user's home directory (`~/.local/share/applications`) is supported, but does not override the system entry in the application menu, and does not affect instances of the application invoked from a default handler for some file type.

Comment: Would you mind to clarify? Do you want an application run different way when started from the menu instead of when started as default application to open certain kind of data files?

Comment: @SPArifSahariWibowo: No. Same for menu and as default handler, adding an environment value to the case of running from system defaults (but without changing the environment of the entire user session).